# Ultrafilters in Social Choice Theory Literature Request

Tags: mathematical-economics, reference-request, social-welfare, social-choice

I am an undergraduate math major who is intrigued about social choice theory. I am in the early stages of planning my senior project and was wondering if anybody had some recommendations of literature about the applications of ultrafilters in social choice theory, along with any other literature you think may be beneficial. The more math the better! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure about what you need. Do you need the proof on how to prove Arrow's impossibility theorem by using a free ultrafilter? In that case, it's an exercise in problem book of set theory.

Comment: That is along the lines of what I am looking for. Thank you! Do you happen to know any quality set theory books off the top of your head?

Comment: I'm a layman of social choice theory. But I think if you are at an early stage of pursuing social choice theory, this article could be of some help. http://www.cs.elte.hu/~kope/ultrafilter.pdf

Comment: This textbook seems to be quite readable. http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Revised-Expanded-Chapman-Mathematics/dp/0824779150/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1428894064&sr=1-1

Comment: You might look at this paper, and the papers citing it: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304406894006843